# Tomcat RemoteIpValve configuration with CDN

Tags: java, iis, cdn, tomcat8, x-forwarded-for

I have Tomcat 8 configured behind IIS 8. Also I have CDN service enabled.

Host has  RemoteIpValve  enabled  as

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"         
        remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
        proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
        protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"/>
```

Log shows as

```
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke Incoming request /api/service/dealer/getStates with originalRemoteAddr '127.0.0.1', originalRemoteHost='127.0.0.1', originalSecure='false', originalScheme='http' will be seen as newRemoteAddr='121.244.190.83', newRemoteHost='121.244.190.83', newScheme='http', newSecure='false'
```

Access log configuration

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="web.hyundai.co.in_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="x-forwarded-for : %{x-forwarded-for}i %h %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
```

And in access log

```
x-forwarded-for : 121.243.37.18, 121.244.190.83 127.0.0.1 [01/Mar/2017:09:02:52 +0530] "GET /api/service/dealer/getStates HTTP/1.1" 200 436
```

Now tomcat is not picking up actual client IP  121.243.37.18 instead it picks the CDN server IP.  I cannot add CDN server IP as a proxy, because, there will be many CDN Edge servers.  How to configure tomcat to get the correct remote IP Address

Answer (score 0):

Does the CDN provide "X-Real-IP" header? 
The x-forwarded-for could be IPs where through more than one proxy.

Comment: x-forwarded was giving comma separated IP including the actual client IP and CDN IP. But for some reason tomcat RemoteIPValve was using the last value (CDN IP) instead of the actual client IP.  So I asked my CDN provided to add customer header true-client-ip and pass the actual remote client IP and that worked.